# Finding if some row fields in Table A is the same of some fields in any row in Table B

Tags: sql

I Have 2 Tables:

Table A {contains fields A1 , A2}

Table B {contains fields B1 , B2 , B3 , B4 , B5 , B6}

My application needs a fast and performant business logic that needs to implement this difficult SQL Query:

select * from Table B where ( **BOTH** A1 and A2 in any Row in Table A) **Exist** in any of the fields of Table B Rows.

as in this Example:

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

[image: The Needed Query Result]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your quesrion

Comment: I need images so that I can highlight the specified Numbers in the Data table Examples with different colors for easy reading. Can I do that without images? It's just numbers so I think it will be difficult to catch the meaning without highlighting it.

Comment: as you can read in the link we need text to use the data, or a dbfiddle as alternativ

Comment: OK I will edit it, thanks.

Comment: Please don't *tag spam*; Ive removed the multiple database vendor tags, please add back the tag for that which you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can do somethin like this, all other databases system can do something
similar

> ```
> CREATE Table A ( A1 int , A2 int);
> INSERT INTO A VALUES( 5,2),(7,1);
>
> CREATE Table B ( B1 int, B2 int, B3 int, B4 int, B5 int, B6 int);
> INSERT INTO B VALUES(5,4,6,1,2,0)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM B 
> WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE FIND_IN_SET(A1,CONCAT(B1,',',B2,',',B3,',',B4,',',B5,',',B6 )))
> AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE FIND_IN_SET(A2,CONCAT(B1,',',B2,',',B3,',',B4,',',B5,',',B6 )))
> ```
>
> ```
> B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 | B6
> -: | -: | -: | -: | -: | -:
>  5 |  4 |  6 |  1 |  2 |  0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=756a26d5cac116bb0cf0b5ed49aef657)*

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `EXISTS` with 2 `IN` will do the trick.

```
select * 
from TableB b
where exists (
    select 1
    from TableA a
    where a.A1 in (b.B1, b.B2, b.B3, b.B4, b.B5, b.B6)
      and a.A2 in (b.B1, b.B2, b.B3, b.B4, b.B5, b.B6)
)
```

*Test on db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0de8758ce82fa1a885f5859b0de37128)*

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just

```
Select * From A,B
Where A.Field1 In (B.Field1, B.Field2, B.Field3, B.Field4, B.Field5, B.Field6, ...)
  And A.Field2 In (B.Field1, B.Field2, B.Field3, B.Field4, B.Field5, B.Field6, ...)
```

?

As far as performance goes, there's probably no way it performs well if both A and B are large.